# Inverse Function like theorem for monotoncity

Tags: calculus

Inverse function theorem says that locally a function is $1-1$ if its derivate is non-zero. Do we have a similar conclusion for monotonous function i.e. statement of the following kind

> If $f(x)$ is continuous and has a non-zero derivative at $x_0$, then their exists an open ball around $x_0$ such that $f(x)$ is monotonous?

Comment: "Open ball" doesn't have much sense over an one variable function. Probably you mean an "interval".

Comment: Consider $f\colon(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\tan(x)$ for rational $x$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.  Now $f$ is continuous  in $x_0=0$ with derivative $f'(0)=1$, but there doesn't exist a neighbourhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is monotonous.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I don't think $f(x)$ is continuous on an interval? It is only continuous at a point.

Comment: Well, you asked for a function, such "$f(x)$ is continuous and has a non-zero derivative at $x_0$".  I gave you one.

Comment: For the "lemma" you want to derive, you may need a more special "smoothness" and characteristics in general of any functions regarded. Simple continuity won't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability is not enough but continuous differentiability is. $f(x) = x^{2}\sin(1/x) + x$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $1$, but is not monotonic on any interval containing $0$.

Comment: Is the theorem well know, if so then can you point out to the source or else can you show me how to prove it?

Comment: It's the Inverse Function Theorem in 1 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f\colon(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\tan(x)$ for rational $x$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.  Now $f$ is continuous  in $x_0=0$ with derivative $f'(0)=1$, but there doesn't exist a neighbourhood of $x_0$ where $f$ is monotonous.

All we can say here that there's a "punctual" monotony: We only can claim that for $x<0<y$ we have $f(x)<f(y)$.

Comment: The $f(x)$ that you construct is not a continuous function on any interval. My question loosely is if $f(x)$ is continuous in an interval, then does their exists an subinterval where $f(x)$ is monotonous.